# a sequence of functions $f_{n+1}\left( x\right)=\int ^{x}_{0}\left( -2y\right) \cdot f_{n}\left( y\right)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\left\{ f_{n}\left( x\right) \right\}$ be a sequence of functions $f_{n}:\mathbb{R} _{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by a recurrence relation $$f_{n+1}\left( x\right)=\int ^{x}_{0}\left( -2y\right) \cdot f_{n}\left( y\right)dy$$ with $f_{0}\left( x\right) =\sinh x .$
**We want to show that** $$\left| f_{n}\left( x\right) \right| \leqslant \dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!}\sinh x.$$ Integrating ( by parts ) one can get explicit formulas for each term, eg: $$\begin{aligned}f_{1}\left( x\right) =2\sinh x-2x\cosh x\\ f_{2}\left( x\right) =\left( 12+4x^{2}\right) \sinh x-12x\cosh x\\ f_{3}\left( x\right) =\left( 110+48x^{2}\right) \sinh x-\left( 120x-8x^{3}\right) \cosh x\\ \ldots, \end{aligned}$$ Still, it not lead to any idea of how to handle the required inequality. ( I tried to use $-\cosh x <-\sinh x$, but it is not working for an upper bound...)
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You formula for $f_2(x)$ has a $y$ in it?  Anyway, it is just simple estimate of the integral noting $\sinh$ is positive and increasing.

Comment: Just a typing error. Already fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by induction. The base case is clear. Now take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and suppose that

$$\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}\sinh x$$

for all $x>0$. Then

\begin{align*}
\lvert f_{n+1}(x)\rvert
&=\left\lvert\int_0^x(-2y)f_n(y)~\mathrm{d}y\right\rvert \\
&\leq\int_0^x2y\lvert f_n(y)\rvert~\mathrm{d}y \\
&\leq\int_0^x\frac{2y^{2n+1}}{n!}\sinh y~\mathrm{d}y \\
&\leq\sinh x\frac{2}{n!}\int_0^xy^{2n+1}~\mathrm{d}y \\
&=\sinh x\frac{2}{n!}\biggl[\frac{y^{2n+2}}{2n+2}\biggr]_0^x \\
&=\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n!(n+1)}\sinh x \\
&=\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}\sinh x
\end{align*}

for all $x>0$, where we used that $0\leq\sinh y\leq \sinh x$ for all $y\in[0,x]$ as $\sinh$ is an increasing function. The result follows by induction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well done! I did not think about it...

Comment: And I still wonder whether a deductive proof rather than an inductive proof is possible for this problem...